# not able to disable select tag

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

There is a li , inside that list i have checkbox(main check box) and another ul,that ul contain a list of checkboxes(sub checkbox) and select tag(sub select). i want that when i uncheck the main check then all the  sub checkboxes should be uncheck and also select tag should be disabled & reset . 
my first part for unchecking the sub checkboxes is working fine but unable to disable and rest the select box .
here is my jquery

```
$('.mainCb').on('change', function () {   
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().find('.subUl').show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find('.subUl').hide();
            $(this).parent().find('.subUl input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
            $(this).parent().find('.subUl input:select').attr('disabled', true); // for disabling select but not able to disable select
        }
    });
```

[My full code Demo here](http://liveweave.com/sxffqx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this,

```
$(this).parent().find('.subUl select').prop('disabled', true);
```

- `input:select` is a wrong selector.
- `.` missing in `subUl` selector - `$(this).parent().find('subUl select')`.
- `var parent = $(this).parent();` use this(caching) instead of calling it everytime.

### [Working Demo](http://liveweave.com/iI1HdU)

```
$('.mainCb').on('change', function () {  
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        parent.find('.subUl').show();
    } else {
        parent.find('.subUl').hide();
        parent.find('.subUl input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
        parent.find('.subUl select').prop('disabled', true); // for disabling select but not able to disable select
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **'.'** in css selector in last statement. Also change 'attr' to 'prop'.

```
$('.mainCb').on('change', function () {   
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().find('.subUl').show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find('.subUl').hide();
            $(this).parent().find('.subUl input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
            $(this).parent().find('.subUl select').prop('disabled', true); // for disabling select but not able to disable select
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Last Statement should be,

```
 $(this).parent().find('.subUl input:select').attr('disabled', true);
```